# How to implement the search function in android

Tags: android, search

how to implement search box like Google apps do in action-bar or else is there any libs for that suggestions, in my app i have custom list view with numbers according to them, i just want to search those numbers that's it any help thanks

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/search/index.html

Comment: i have custom list view and numbers assigned to it, i just want to search for numbers that i assigned for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add Item menu Search !

```
  <item
    android:id="@+id/option_menu_search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
    android:orderInCategory="10"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    android:title="@string/abc_searchview_description_search"
    >
```

add in your onOptionsItemSelected

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.option_menu_search).getActionView();
```

then

```
 searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                return true;
            } });
```

Comment: thanks, its working but can you tell me how to search for number

Comment: Add to your list Adapter (Sample Adapter) ! 
`mAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);`